# Restore only specific data from .BAK File using php

Tags: php, sql-server, restore

I am using SQL Server 2014 & php. I have two apps one in cloud and another in local
I make a backup from the cloud every hour and take this `.bak` file and restore it to local database.

How can I restore only new data was which inserted into the database because it takes long time to be restored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use differential backup. Look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/differential-backups-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)